# Fortran77 Casting integer to a String

Tags: string, casting, integer, fortran77

Out of interest, I was trying to find a way to cast an integer to a String in Fortran77.
I came across `CHAR(I)`, but this converts the ASCII index I into the character in that postion.
Is there a way to just simply cast an integer to a String in Fortran77?
How about vice versa?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Fortran way is to write the value of the integer into a string variable; this operation is known as an *internal write*.  I'm heading out the door now so won't check this, and I have an ethical objection to writing FORTRAN77 or helping anyone else write it, so make no guarantee that the following doesn't contain bits of more modern Fortran.

First declare a character variable to receive the integer

```
character(len=12) :: int_as_string
```

then write the integer into it as you would normally write an integer to any other channel such as `stdout`

```
write(int_as_string,'(i12.12)') my_int
```

I expect you'll want to set the format for writing the integer to something that suits you better

Comment: yea I agree with you on the ethical objection part. thanks a lot!

Comment: what's the ethical objection? Is it just painful to code in? It's not like an environmental objection, is it? Like they have to chop down millions of trees for punch cards.